# What is the difference between half space and hyper plane?

Tags: geometry

I read about half space and hyper plane and keep getting confused about which is which and how people are using it. I would really appreciate if somebody can give me an example in simple language over the math one written on wikipedia.[Half Space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-space_%28geometry%29)

I made a mistake of writing half planes instead of hyper plane. Corrected it.

Comment: Half space = half plane in dimension 2.

Comment: In a word, the difference is the difference between “$\ge$” and “$=$”.

Answer (score 13):

A hyperplane is a subset of a Euclidean space of one less dimension than the whole space.  As such, it is defined by one linear equation.  In $\mathbb R^3$, the plane created by the $x$ and $y$ axes is one such, represented by $z=0$.  The plane $x+y+z=0$ is another, tilted and going through the origin.  Each side of such a plane is a half space.  The same happens in higher dimensions.  If the coordinates are $x_1, x_2, \ldots ,x_n$, there is a hyperplane $x_1=5$ which divides the space into two half spaces:  one with all points that satisfy $x_1 \gt 5$ and one with the ones that have $x_1 \lt 5$.  Similarly, there is another with $x_1+4x_2+3x_3 = 9$ which is inclined in those axes.

Answer (score 3):

Intuitive answer for non-mathematicians:

A hyperplane divides a higher dimensional space into two **half-spaces**. 
A **half-plane** is one of the halves after the hyperplane has been split in two.

For **example**, if we cut a piece of *cheese* in half, the place where we cut is the hyperplane, while the *two pieces* are the *half-spaces*.

If we imagine that the knife forms a hyperplane, than if we split the *blade* into *two*, we will get *half-planes*.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, half-plane is just another name to a half-space in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. The general definition is half-spaces requires some understanding of linear algebra, and the wikipedia article covers it pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

Mathworld article on [Half-space](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Half-Space.html) relates half-space and hyperplane clearly as(quoting from the article):

> A half-space is that portion of an n-dimensional space obtained by removing that part lying on one side of an (n-1)-dimensional hyperplane.